# Following (a) training: verb and pronoun

Tags: pronouns, uncountable-nouns

I am not a native English speaker but I work in an organisation with English as corporate language. I have set up an automatic reply because I was following a 3-day course, and I have received a remark about the wording used in my message.

Is "I'm following training from Monday 5th to Wednesday 7th." correct?

Two questions:

- Is the verb "follow" appropriate?
- I know the word "training" is uncountable, and therefore no pronoun ("a") is required. Is it correct?

Thank you

Comment: The correct word choice is "attending" rather than "following." An off-topic hint: unless your company requires you to state the reason for your absence, you should probably not do so. Why let a correspondent know that you needed "training"?

Comment: Thank you. Would "I'm attending training" be correct? Or do I need to write "I'm attending a training" ?
Regarding the off-topic hint, it depends. I'm in an organisation promoting continuous skills building. There is nothing wrong to have my colleagues know I follow a course.

Comment: "I'm attending training" or, maybe better, "I'm attending a training program/course."

Comment: It's only my internal automatic reply. I don't let my clients know that I'm not available unless I'm on holiday. I'm very surprised by how you consider a person attending a training course. Do you prefer someone who learn and keep progressing or someone who is satisfied by his level of knowledge and does not make efforts to evolve ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way it could be written is:
I will be unavailable between Monday 5th and Wednesday 7th, as I will be at a training course.

You could even be more specific with the date:
e.g. Monday March 5 and Wednesday March 7